# Mimic browser URL encoding for Chinese characters?

Tags: php, http, url, utf-8, url-encoding

If you go here: http://hdjob.bjx.com.cn/AdvanceSearch.shtml

And find in the source HTML:

```
<dd><a href="/SearchResult.aspx?workprovince=安徽" target="_blank">安徽</a></dd>
```

If you place your cursor over the link in Chrome or Firefox, or simply open it up, the URL would look like this:

```
http://hdjob.bjx.com.cn/SearchResult.aspx?workprovince=%B0%B2%BB%D5
```

So the Chinese characters `安徽` are URL encoded as `%B0%B2%BB%D5` automatically by the browsers.

My question is how to mimic this in PHP?

I tried these:

```
echo urlencode("安徽"), PHP_EOL;
echo rawurlencode("安徽");
```

Which output:

```
%E5%AE%89%E5%BE%BD
%E5%AE%89%E5%BE%BD
```

However if you go to:

http://hdjob.bjx.com.cn/SearchResult.aspx?workprovince=%E5%AE%89%E5%BE%BD

It's simply the wrong page and the `workprovince` variable isn't decoded correctly at all.

Seems both Chrome and Firefox are encoding the Chinese characters in a different way than both **urlencode**() and **rawurlencode**()?

How to mimic their way of doing this in PHP then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 echo urlencode(mb_convert_encoding('安徽', 'gb2312', 'utf-8')); //  %B0%B2%BB%D5
 echo urlencode('安徽'); // %E5%AE%89%E5%BE%BD
```